# Are sony lto6 tapes mp or bf?

Tags: tape, lto

Most lto tapes specify MP or BaFe on their labels. Sony ltx2500g tapes dont.
I have two ibm lto6 decks and want to try to keep different tape brands and particle formulations on different machines just to make it easier to isolate tape/head problems in case there are any.
So far I have not had problems with any tape, but fuji bafe tapes do seem to be much slower writing. They are the only BF tapes I have tried. Other brands I used are HP (MP version) and Sony, both of which work fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SONY LTO-6 uses MP as a magnetic particle. See the URL below: https://www.bcs.tv/store/prod_detail.cfm?eq_id=512810